# Attempting Android Stagefright on Virtual Software

Tags: exploit, android, stagefright

Does anyone know how I can exploit an android vm using stagefright?  I can't use the android AVK because it doesn't support MMS.

Comment: I think it's probably easier to buy a crappy Android phone for $50 to test on.